# UISeachBar and keyboard appearing, disappearing, and then appearing again

Tags: uitableview, keyboard, uisearchbar

I have a UISearchBar which can become first responder. In the same screen I have a tableview whose rows the user can touch to go to a new screen. However, when the search bar is active and the keyboard is up, if the user touches one of the table rows to go to a new screen and then goes back, the keyboard reappears, disappears, and then appears again one last time. Any ideas what's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are popping view controller back after pushing. See if there is this line

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

you have in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear method of the next screen